# Trim and merge audio and video file using ffmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to trim an audio file and then merge it with my video file on android.

I can merge them together with the command below

```
String command[] = {"-i", mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath(), " -i", mOutputAudioFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac","-shortest", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

But i need to trim the beginning (half-second for example) of my audio file before (for synchronization issue). So if you can help me with a single command it would be perfect but maybe i can just run two ffmpeg commands successively but i don't know how to do that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i solved the problem, it was just about syntax, i had to write

```
{"-i", mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-ss", "0.5", "-i", mOutputAudioFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-shortest", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply a seek option to the audio:

```
String command[] = {"-i", mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath(), " -ss 0.5", " -i", mOutputAudioFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac","-shortest", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

This will start the audio feed from 0.5 seconds.

Comment: I already tried something like that but that doesn't work, no output file is created... I tried also ' "-ss" + 0.5 ' but nothing happen...

Comment: Add `-report` and share the report.